# Wordpress typing test effect only one tyme in one session

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have wordpress website, I have added typing test line in my **navigation-top.php** file, and it works fine.
I want it to work just one time per session, so when someone clicks on menu categories, or on product the effect don't work anymore

I just have no idea how I can do it

here are the code I used

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    document.getElementById("typing-demo-div").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("typing-demo-div").setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
  }
}
```

```css
#typing-demo-div{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:10px;
}
#typing-demo{
    color:black;
width: 90%; 
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-animation: typing 10s steps(200, end),
blink-caret .15s step-end infinite alternate;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:static;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing { from { width: 0; } }

.bisbankstyle{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#F45D48;
}
```

```html
<div id="typing-demo-div">
    <div id="typing-demo">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use sessionStorage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage